# basic processor architectures

Tags: cpu-architecture, processor

I am confused with the basic processor architectures. It's better if somebody can clearly and very simply explain me the differences of each of the following architectures with the help of diagrams.

1. Accumulator based architecture
2. Stack based architecture
3. Memory to memory architecture
4. Register based architecture

And also I need to know the differences between the two subjects - Computer Architecture and Processor Architecture.

Comment: I think there is a lot of literature available out there to answer those fundamental questions, notably [Hennessy and Patterson](https://www.elsevier.com/books/computer-architecture/hennessy/978-0-12-811905-1) or [Tanenbaum](https://www.pearson.com/us/higher-education/program/Tanenbaum-Structured-Computer-Organization-6th-Edition/PGM200985.html), for example. Also, Google and Wikipedia should be of help.

Comment: I need a sample assembly code for each of the above with diagrammatic representations. Wikipedia has meshed it up.

Answer (score 1):

The difference is where the arguments for the ALU comes from and where they are stored, few CPU's are pure one or the other.

1. One of the arguments usually comes from the Accumulator and the result is usually stored in the Accumulator.
2. Arguments are pulled from the stack and the result is put back on the stack.
3. Arguments are pulled from memory and the result is written back to some (possible other) memory position.
4. Arguments are typically taken from registers and the result is written back to (possible other) register.

So 1. is a specialization of 4. and 2. is a specialization of 3.

This [article](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/461052/Stack-based-vs-Register-based-Virtual-Machine-Arch) has some nice pictures of stack and register machines.

Comment: Stack machines can have addressable main memory, can't they?  With instructions to push from memory to stack, or pop from top of stack to memory.  Something needs to be random-access.  So the stack is an alternative to registers, not to memory, I think.

Comment: @PeterCordes, what I meant by specialization, is that stack machines only take arguments from stack as opposed to memory architectures that can take from anywhere. But you are right that stack machines must get their stack from somewhere, hence they are not pure.